# Multiple roots for roots of unity in fields of some characteristic

Tags: roots, roots-of-unity, positive-characteristic

I'm currently working through Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography, L. C. Washington.

The bottom of page 82 says "Since the characteristic of $K$ does not divide $n$, the equation $x^n = 1$ has no multiple roots, hence has $n$ roots in $\overline{K}$."

Why is this true? I'm aware that if a polynomial $f(x)$ has a root which is also a root to $f'(x)$, then that root is a multiple root, but I feel like I'm missing a step to deduce the sentence.

Comment: I'm not sure what $K$ is or context, but I vaguely recall I thin, Cayley Hamilton theorem that something or other satisfies it's own characteristic equation, then something... Maybe related.

Comment: $K$ is just a field (I thought that it would be obvious in this context because $\overline{K}$ typically refers to the algebraic closure), and talking about the characteristic of $K$ implies that it is a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^n-1$. Then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$. If the characteristic of $K$ does not divide $n$, then $f'\ne0$ and so $\gcd(f,f')=1$.

Conversely, if the characteristic of $K$ is $p$ and $n=mp$, then $x^n-1=x^{mp}-1=(x^m-1)^p$. Therefore, every root of $x^m-1$ is a multiple root of $x^n-1$.

Comment: Doesn't this prove the converse of the statement?

Comment: @IrregularUser, you're right. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ah, so simple and obvious, thanks.